# Update nested entities in isolation from one another using JPA/Hibernate/Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have an entity (EntityA) with another entity (EntityB) nested inside it. I want to update the **username** and **lastUpdateDatetime** of each entity in isolation if there is a change on a specific entity, without the other entity being updated.

i.e.

- if a change is made on entityB, only the username and lastUpdateDatetime on entityB should be updated
- if a change is made on entityA, only the username and lastUpdateDatetime on entityA should be updated

Here are my 2 entities:

EntityA:

```
    @Entity(name = "EntityA")
    public class EntityA {
        
        @Column(name = "EntityAColumn1")
        private String entityAColumn1;
    
        @Column(name = "EntityAColumn2")
        private String entityAColumn2;     
    
        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "EntityA_EntityB")
        private EntityB entityB;
    
        @Column(name = "username", length = 100)
        private String username;
    
        @Column(name = "last_update_datetime")
        private ZonedDateTime lastUpdateDatetime;
    }
```

EntityB:

```
    @Entity(name = "EntityB")
    public class EntityB {
        
        @Column(name = "EntityBColumn1")
        private String entityBColumn1;
    
        @Column(name = "EntityBColumn2")
        private String entityBColumn2;     
    
        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "EntityB", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private EntityA entityA;
    
        @Column(name = "username", length = 100)
        private String username;
    
        @Column(name = "last_update_datetime")
        private ZonedDateTime lastUpdateDatetime;
    }
```

**Note that there is a one-to-one relationship between the entities.**

Here is my controller class for updating the entity:

```
    @RestController
    public class EntityAController {
    
        private final EntityARepository entityARepository;
    
        @PutMapping("/update")
        public void updateEntityA(
            @RequestBody ObjectA objectA,
            @RequestHeader("username") String username
        ) {
            EntityA entityA = EntityMapper.mapToEntity(objectA);
    
            entityARepository.save(entityA);
        }
    }
```

**EntityMapper.mapToEntity(objectA); simply maps my web request to my entity**

My repository class looks as follows:

```
    @Repository("EntityARepository")
    public interface ShippingOrderRepository extends CrudRepository<EntityA, Long> {
        
    }
```

Now let's say my database entry looks like this before an update:

**NOTE: My database is relational, I'm just writing it in json format for readability**

```
    {
        "entityAColumn1": "val1",
        "entityAColumn2": "val2",
        "entityB": {
            "entityBColumn1": "val3",
            "entityBColumn2": "val4",
            "username": "username1",
            "lastUpdateDatetime": 2023-09-20T07:09:30Z
        },
        "username": "username1",
        "lastUpdateDatetime": 2023-09-20T07:09:30Z
    }
```

I then send in the following request to my controller:

```
    {
        "entityAColumn1": "val1",
        "entityAColumn2": "val2",
        "entityB": {
            "entityBColumn1": "val3",
            "entityBColumn2": "val5", **VALUE HAS CHANGED**
            "username": "username1",
            "lastUpdateDatetime": 2023-09-20T07:09:30Z
        },
        "username": "username1",
        "lastUpdateDatetime": 2023-09-20T07:09:30Z
    }
```

- **entityBColumn2** was changed on entityB
- With the "username" in the requestHeader set to "username2".

My **desired outcome** is for the data to reflect as follows in the database:

```
    {
        "entityAColumn1": "val1",
        "entityAColumn2": "val2",
        "entityB": {
            "entityBColumn1": "val3",
            "entityBColumn2": "val5", //UPDATED
            "username": "username2", //UPDATED
            "lastUpdateDatetime": 2023-10-13T07:09:30Z //UPDATED
        },
        "username": "username1",
        "lastUpdateDatetime": 2023-09-20T07:09:30Z
    }
```

**Only EntityB's username and lastUpdateDatetime has been updated, because it's the only entity that has undergone a change.**

But i've been unable to achieve this.

I've tried:

- Using a @PreUpdate annotated function on my entities, but both entities still end up getting updated even if a change is only present on one.

```
    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate() {
        this.username = UsernameUtil.getUserName();
        this.lastUpdateDateTime = ZonedDatetime.now();
    }
```

- Using @UpdateTimestamp as a way to update my lastUpdateDatetime, but it also results in both entities getting updated.

```
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "last_update_datetime")
    private ZonedDateTime lastUpdateDatetime;
```

I want to **avoid** writing a comparison method to detect changes as follows:

```
    public boolean EntityHasChanged(EntityA oldEntity, EntityA newEntity) {
        
        if(oldentity.getEntityAColumn1() != newEntity.getEntityAColumn1()) {
            return true;
        }
    
        // other comparisons
    }
```

because if an entity has 100 fields it just becomes impractical.

**NOTE: I have a mechanism for storing the username received in the request header and later using it to set the username, I just left it out because it is irrelevant to my question**

So finally my question is:

Is there some sort of JPA/hibernate mechanism that can help me achieve my goal of updating my enities' username and lastUpdateDatetime in isolation if a change is only made to a certain entity, without writing a massive comparison function for each entity?

Please let me know if you require any more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized my mistake. There was code elsewhere in my code base that was manually setting the `lastUpdateDatetime` on my entities to `ZonedDatetime.now()`.

This naturally caused my `@PreUpdate` function to always fire and always set my `lastUpdateDatetime` and `username`.

I removed the code where I manually set my `lastUpdateDatetime` and made use of the `@UpdateTimestamp` annotation on my `lastUpdateDatetime` and a `@PreUpdate` function on my entities to set the `username`.

Using this approach I was able to update my `lastUpdateDatetime` and `username` only on entities that had undergone a change.